# eval() not working in wordpress plugin code

Tags: php, wordpress

since I am new to wordpress plugin development I am trying create a shortcode based plugin. I am trying to run the php code enclosed in the shortcode. The shortcode is working fine but the eval() that I use in shortcode handler is throwing some parse error:

> **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ‘&’ in XXXXX.php(32) : eval()’d code on line 1**

shortcode handler:

```
if(is_null($content)){
   return " ";
}else{
   ob_start();
   eval($content);
   $evaluated_content = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_flush();
   return $evaluated_content;
}
```

shortcode usage:

> [shortcode]echo 'hello';[/shortcode]

Please help me out.

**Update:** there is no problem in the code i find thats why i am asking this question i have already gone through the previously answered questions but there no such error in my code i'm simply echoing hello. and one more thing if i pass the same code as a string to eval() directly then it works fine but when the string is coming from shortcode then it gives the parse error

Comment: @JohnConde this is not duplicate this is something else then that see the update i added and if you think it is already been solved then give me the solution to this problem.....